# Pandas groupby multiple column then subplot

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, subplot

I have a simple issue that I would appreciate if someone can help me with

I'm grouping a dataframe by two columns to create a multiindex dataframe.
Then, I want to create a bar plot for each each group:

```
df.groupby(['Teacher_name','Class_name'], sort = True).Student_ID.count()
```

Here is an image of the bar plots I'm looking for, i.e., a plot for each teacher with the number of students in each class.

[image: click here to see the image of the barplots im looking for]

Comment: What is you question exactly? This site is not here to let others your homework done. Work on the problem and come back with specific questions, a clear description what you've done so far and what you want to achieve.

Comment: the question is brief , is how to sublot multi index table .. your comment is valid but not in this case , as im trying to find a solution to that problem and not asking someone to solve my homework. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should install plotly and use the wonderful plotly express like this :

```py
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(df, x="Class_name", facet_col="Teacher_name")
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=600, height=300) # resize figure
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ismail for the beautiful explanation, however this is not the part im struggling with. 
in my example i have three variables, the last one is the count of the students. what i need to plot in the bar is the count of students in each class.

Comment: Yes my answer also works if you have a third column student_id because it shows the count  of rows for each unique pair (teacher, class), so it is actually like counting students for each pair.